# How to get vscode TreeView instance of workbench.view.debug

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to get the `TreeView` instance of a builtin view like `"workbench.view.debug"`. This would allow me to experiment with edit masks on input, maybe cancel onclick events based on `TreeViewItem` type, and more.

The [vscode-extension-samples](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples) all use `createTreeView()` which creates a new `TreeView` object. I've even tried to override the buitin `viewId` with

```
this.dbgvaredtView=window.createTreeView( 'workbench.view.debug',{treeDataProvider: this.dbgvaredt}
```

..but this only creates a new `TreeView`.

How can I obtain a `TreeView` instance of `"workbench.view.debug"`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can only obtain a `TreeView` instance of views you created yourself. The VSCode API generally doesn't give extension authors much control over built-in UI, apart from adding context menu items and such.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create "an instance" of the `TreeView` like the `Debug View` you're trying to. You need to create a new view with a new name for it to show up. If you are trying to get this new `View` in the `Debug Viewlet`, then you will have to set it in the extension `package.json`.